# web config header side effect

Tags: .net, iis, header, web-config

I added the following header value to web.config to fix security vulnerability in operation / development environment.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsage-inline' 'unsage-eval'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' script-src 'self';" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1" />
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="Max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
        <add name="X-Frame-options" value="ALLOW-FROM http://@@@.@@@.com/@@@/login.jsp" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

However, in the operating environment, the call to http started to be called with https. When I called http again, the browser arbitrarily redirected to https.

We removed the header values we added to see why, but https was still being cached in the browser. Now I can not modify the source in the operating environment, so I can not test it. I wonder if any of these headers play such a role.

Development environment and operating environment I have configured the config just the same, but I do not understand why there is a difference. The difference I notice is that SSL certificates are operational and SSL certificates are private, so there is a certificate error.

Comment: Clean the cache of your browser to test it again

Comment: @reds We can not do it because we canceled the release of the operating environment.
This is because previous developers have developed the source so that calling the page with https results in a bug.

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, isn't that exactly how HSTS is supposed to work? Cached by the browser so the browser automatically upgrades all connections to https?

Comment: @Ic. Yes it is. We just modified web.config. Despite the same application of web.config in the production / development environment, this phenomenon only occurs in the operating environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the **cache-control** header to force the server to post resources from the server instead of caching. Of course you can remove them after sometime, say the expiry of you **max-age**, as you would be sure, a new resource is requested after the max-age duration.